# The printf `h` length qualifier and variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c, printf, ellipsis

If `bool`, `char`s and `short`s are promoted to `int`s when passed through an ellipsis parameter, what's the point of the `h` length qualifier of `printf` if `printf` will read `int`s anyway?

NOTE: I'm more interested in the semantics and intented purpose of the `h` length qualifier from a C++ perspective, in case there's any difference respect to `C`, although I guess it doesn't.

Comment: This is probably better posted as a C question, since the C++ standard includes printf by reference to C specification

Comment: anyway, the answer is that they are obviously important for `scanf` (and `printf` with `%n`), so included in general printf for symmetry